# Understanding reductions for NP-completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

Let's I have to make the following reduction:

$$\text{CLIQUE}\le_p \text{VERTEX-COVER}$$

The technique of building the reduction is -

1. Assume you can find a $\text{VERTEX-COVER}$ of size $k$, in polynomial time.
2. Building a new graph, in which I say that if a $\text{VERTEX-COVER}$ exists of size $k$, then in the original graph, a $\text{CLIQUE}$ of size $k$ exists?

I just want to understand the technique of these proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Assume you can find a $vertex-cover$ of size $k$, in polynomial time.

Actually, this step is not correct. When we show that $A \le_p B$, where $A$ and $B$ are languages (also known as decision problems), we do not assume that either $A$ or $B$ can be solved in polynomial time. What we do is "reduce" problem $A$ to problem $B$: that means that we take an instance of problem A, and return an instance of problem $B$. The part that has to be polynomial time is this "reduce" function.

In other words, it's possible that $A$ and $B$ are both really "hard" -- they can't be done in polynomial time, or maybe they aren't even decidable. But what we show is that the *reduction* is polynomial time.

So what is this "reduction" that we have to show is polynomial time? You mentioned part of it:

> 2. Building a new graph, in which I say that if a $vertex-cover$ exists of size $k$, then in the original graph, a $clique$ of size $k$ exists?

That's half. You also have to show that if a vertex-cover *doesn't* exist of size $k$, then in the original graph, a clique of size $k$ *doesn't* exist.

**To summarize:** when doing a reduction from $A$ to $B$ ($A \le_p B$), here are the three things you should show:

1. If the output of the reduction is in $B$, then the input is in $A$. (For example, if a vertex-cover exists in the output, then in the original graph, a clique exists.)
2. If the output of the reduction is *not* in $B$, then the input is *not* in $A$. (For example, if a vertex-cover does not exist in the output, then in the original graph, a clique does not exist).
3. The whole reduction -- which takes instances of problem $A$ to instances of problem $B$ -- runs in polynomial time.